# Vue.js: Only load component if user clicks button

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have code that looks like the code below. how do I set this up so the components "dataPart1' and "dataPart2" won't load unless a user clicks a button to view the data? In other words, I don't want the data to just automatically show, but only if the user chooses to see it via a button click option.

```
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#data',
  data: {
    show: true,
    something: true,
  },
  components: {
    dataPart1,
    dataPart2
  },
  ...other stuff...
  }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"load"_? Do you mean you don't want the component definitions to be loaded, saving bandwidth or do you mean you just don't want them to display?

Comment: hi @Phil by load i want the definitions to be loaded

Comment: Then why have you accepted an answer that does not do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to conditionally display content in the templates (text, html, components, etc), we can use [conditional rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html) of Vue.js and specifically `v-if` directive.

Short explanation: we can display content depending on certain variables defined in our component. And change value of that variable on certain events, e.g. button click.

Please, take a look at example on CodeSandbox of loading two components conditionally on buttons clicks.

In `App.vue` file, we have 2 buttons that trigger a handler on click and display component's if corresponding value is `true`.

[image: Edit Vue Template]

Comment: is there a way to add a new component each time I click on a single button? then I would use a close button in each component so it works properly.

Comment: Displaying and Mounting are 2 separate things...